# How to fix wp-config.php to upload pictures in WordPress?

Tags: php, html, wordpress, host

I have the following site http://imosigbroker.ro/. Logo and some pictures have been broken after I migrated the localhost site on the host. I tried to add these photos manually in WP via `Media > Select Files` and I got the following message error: "Missing a temporary file."

I set all DB files from localhost to my site with a plugin. This is not the issue of the website right now.

The debug shown the following:

> **Notice:** Constant WP_DEBUG already defined in /home/imosigbr/public_html/wp-config.php on line 96
>
> **Notice:** Constant SCRIPT_DEBUG already defined in /home/imosigbr/public_html/wp-config.php on line 97
>
> **Warning:** Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /home/imosigbr/public_html/wp-config.php:96) in /home/imosigbr/public_html/wp-admin/includes/misc.php on line 1196

I followed these tutorials [1]: https://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-tutorials/how-to-fix-missing-a-temporary-folder-error-in-wordpress/ [2]:https://www.wpbeginner.com/beginners-guide/how-to-fix-file-and-folder-permissions-error-in-wordpress/ and although the pictures were not fixed.

Comment: Remove the duplicate constant declarations. The _Cannot modify header information_  is likely just a result of the first two notices outputting text already.

Comment: Your images are still pointing to localhost which is why they don't load.

Answer (score 0):

Hi the other commenters are right. Go to PHPMyadmin on your control panel and select your database then in the SQL box at the top paste :

```
UPDATE wp_options SET option_value = replace(option_value, 'http://localhost', 'http://imosigbroker.ro/') WHERE option_name = 'home' OR option_name = 'siteurl';

UPDATE wp_posts SET guid = replace(guid, 'http://www.localhost','http://imosigbroker.ro/');

UPDATE wp_posts SET post_content = replace(post_content, 'http://localhost', 'http://imosigbroker.ro/');

UPDATE wp_postmeta SET meta_value = replace(meta_value,'http://localhost','http://imosigbroker.ro/');
```

then click run. It will do a proper job of updating your URLS throughout the site.